# How can I count the replys of a post in twitter?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

With tweepy we know that is possible to count the likes and retweets from a tweet. Is it possible to count the replys too? For example is it possible to do something like that:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=name).items(1):
         print(str(status.reply_count))
```

To be clear I don't want to retrive all replys from a given post. I just want the number of these replys.

Comment: have a look in the incoming `json` - print status.keys() and you will see :)

Comment: Is it possible with tweepy though? Do you have any source that you can share? My question might be duplicated. If you have seen any post that this question has been answered and you can share it, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: well thinking about it now, I do not think it is possible. You can find out if a tweet is a reply of some tweet in `u'in_reply_to_status_id` field. But if someone tweets in a thread, then all the tweets above would have to be changed, which would mean changing all the tweets's attributes. That is not going to happend

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible - Tweet objects do not contain this data so the API call in tweepy you propose would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help for getting a count of comments and all post data.

```
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    import tweepy
    pages="xyz";
    for full_tweets in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=pages).items(10):
            replyCounter=0
            try:
                #for getting comment count
                for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='to:' + pages, result_type='recent').items(10):
                    if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
                        if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str == full_tweets.id_str):
                            replyCounter+=1

            except IOError as e:
                print("ERRROE===>",e.message)

            # time.sleep(2)

            # print("response=====>",full_tweets._json)
            print(str(page)+" Postname =====>",full_tweets.text)
            print(str(page)+" Likes =====>",full_tweets.favorite_count)
            print(str(page)+" Share=====>",full_tweets.retweet_count)
            print(str(page)+" Comment=====>",replyCounter)
            print(str(page)+" PostLINK=====>","https://twitter.com/"+str(page)+"/status/"+str(full_tweets.id_str))
            print(str(page) + " _record_" + str(counter) + "=====>close")

            writer.writerow({'Posted Date':full_tweets.created_at,
                             'Postname': full_tweets.text,
                             'Likes': full_tweets.favorite_count,
                             'Share': full_tweets.retweet_count,
                             'Comment': replyCounter,
                             'PostLink': "https://twitter.com/"+str(page)+"/status/"+str(full_tweets.id_str),
                             })
            counter+=1

except IOError as e:
    print("ERROR occured==>",e.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

The twitter API is having different version, v1.1 and v2. Tweepy wasn't supporting v2 by the time (and still in developpement).

You can get some help here : [Is there any way to get the number of comments on a tweet using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395855/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-number-of-comments-on-a-tweet-using-python/67437455#67437455)