# Is there any way to get the number of comments on a tweet using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy and it does not seem like there is a way to scrape the number of comments on a particular tweet from a user. I can use the `tweet.favorite_count` and `tweet.retweet_count` to get favorites and retweets but I am looking for a way to get the number of comments on that post. I don't even need to see what the comments are. Just the quantity. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here -- tweets don't have "comments". Do you mean _replies_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you meant *replies*. Anyway, all you have to do is carefully inspect the page source (CTRL+F and search for "replies"), so you can know what to look for in a `BeautifulSoup` object later on:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://twitter.com/Cristiano/status/912028229011169281')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

comments = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria'})[0].contents

print(*comments)
```

...output:

> 9,370 replies

Comment: this doesn't use `tweepy` though?

Comment: No, it does not. The question was "*Is there any way to get the number of comments on a tweet using python?*", there is no mention of *tweepy*.

Comment: This method uses web scraping, which is in violation of Twitter's rules and policies. You should use the Twitter API instead. You would need to use the Search API to find and count replies to a Tweet, however.

Answer (score 1):

## Different version of Twitter API and their tweepy support

Twitter API is having 2 different versions, v1.1 and v2. The v1 do not permit to get comment count, only retweets & likes. The v2 support [metrics](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics) and allow to it.

Tweepy, when using `tweepy.API` support only v1. When writing this answer [05/07], a support for v2 is currently in [development](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1472). [Tweepy features](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/client.html) to interact with v2 API are only available in master branch for development purpose.

### Tweepy using Twitter API v2

Install tweepy with the production branch:
`pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git`

Retrieve number of comments (and other tweet metrics) :

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token="YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN")
client_result = client.get_tweet(1387426242060767234, \
      tweet_fields=["public_metrics"])
tweet = client_result.data

print(tweet.public_metrics["reply_count"])
```

P.S. : As the features is in developpement, things could change and post should be updated.